# Can't get ARK editor to replace Tiny Editor

Tags: plugin

I have Joomla 3.5 on Windows pro 7.
I went and downloaded Ark Editor. Extention Manager says it is successfully installed.

Go to global configurations to activate, but is not showning in drop down menu.

Comment: Did you install the free extensions or are you using a subscription? https://arkextensions.com/documentation/ark-editor/247-installing-the-ark-editor-with-the-extensions-manager Please confirm that you have followed all the steps outlined in the link above.

Comment: As far as I know the Ark I downloaded was free and not a subscription. In fact, I don't recall seeing anything concerning a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also seeing a warning that the component wasn't found, try clearing your site's cache: **System > Clear Cache > Delete All**

Good luck!